# Use a class constructor in Android

Tags: android, constructor, instantiation

I need to instantiate a class in the MainActivity class .Therefore i used the constructor defined on the class but the problem it includes some parameters that i dont know how to instantiate with.

this is the class constructor:(please see the comments)

```
public class FallbackLocationTracker  implements LocationTracker, LocationTracker.LocationUpdateListener {


private boolean isRunning;

private ProviderLocationTracker gps;
private ProviderLocationTracker net;

private LocationUpdateListener listener;

Location lastLoc;
long lastTime;

public FallbackLocationTracker(Context context, ProviderLocationTracker.ProviderType type) {
    gps = new ProviderLocationTracker(context, ProviderLocationTracker.ProviderType.GPS);
    net = new ProviderLocationTracker(context, ProviderLocationTracker.ProviderType.NETWORK);
}
```

And this is what i have done in the Mainactivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

GPSTracker gps;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    gps = new FallbackLocationTracker( );//What should i do here to make use of the class and all the methods ??

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new FallbackLocationTracker(this,ProviderLocationTracker.ProviderType.NETWORK);
```

Comment: Which still doesn't make much sense because he isn't using the second parameter inside that constructor. O well.

Comment: true - but perhaps he might want to use it later on - hard to say without more info

Comment: I m using this example from this website to get user location :
http://gabesechansoftware.com/location-tracking/
The problem i m facing is how to call and use those classes in my mainactivity ?